# Create a list from df based on a column type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I am getting a df from running a sql query using **pymssql**

```
data = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
data

addr    value  d_no
=========================
XXX     1       A
YYY     2       B
XXX     3       C
XXX     4       D
YYY     5       E
ZZZ     6       F
ZZZ     7       G
ZZZ     8       H
```

I want to split the df into a list of df. i was able to do that using

```
batches = [d for _, d in data.groupby(['addr'])]
```

```
[
addr    value  d_no
=========================
XXX     1       A
XXX     3       C
XXX     4       D         ,
addr    value  d_no
=========================
YYY     2       B
YYY     5       E         ,
addr    value  d_no
=========================
ZZZ     6       F
ZZZ     7       G
ZZZ     8       H
]
```

The list has split based on the **addr**. but i need to split it in a way where each df in a list has only 2 values and should be also of same **addr** something like below,

```
[
addr    value  d_no
=========================
XXX     1       A
XXX     3       C         ,
addr    value  d_no
=========================
XXX     4       D         ,
addr    value  d_no
=========================
YYY     2       B
YYY     5       E         ,
addr    value  d_no
=========================
ZZZ     6       F
ZZZ     7       G         ,
addr    value  d_no
=========================
ZZZ     8       H
]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *range* split:

```
batches = [d.iloc[i:i+2] for _, d in df.groupby('addr') 
           for i in range(0, d.index.size, 2)]
```

---

```
[  addr  value d_no
 0  XXX      1    A
 2  XXX      3    C,
   addr  value d_no
 3  XXX      4    D,
   addr  value d_no
 1  YYY      2    B
 4  YYY      5    E,
   addr  value d_no
 5  ZZZ      6    F
 6  ZZZ      7    G,
   addr  value d_no
 7  ZZZ      8    H]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more grouper based on the [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) of the group [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
group = data.groupby('addr').cumcount().floordiv(2)
batches = [d for _, d in data.groupby(['addr', group])]
```

Output:

```
[  addr  value d_no
 0  XXX      1    A
 2  XXX      3    C,
   addr  value d_no
 3  XXX      4    D,
   addr  value d_no
 1  YYY      2    B
 4  YYY      5    E,
   addr  value d_no
 5  ZZZ      6    F
 6  ZZZ      7    G,
   addr  value d_no
 7  ZZZ      8    H]
```